# QT 4.8.5 compile error in CentOS 5.X

Tags: qt, centos, gcc4, gcc4.7

I have download the Qt-everywhere-4.8.5.tar.gz from Qt official website. And In the CentOS 5.X, it's GCC version is 4.1.2. So I have compiled the `gcc-4.7.2` from source code and installed it in `$HOME/software/`, then in the install directory, there are `bin` and `lib` and `lib64`, and I have add the path into `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Then, I uncompressed the qt source code, configure it with

```
    ./configure -prefix $HOME/softwares/ -nomake demos -nomake examples
```

Then, make it. there is an error:

```
    /home/user/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.5/bin/lrelease:assistant_cs.ts -qm assistant_cs.qm
    /home/user/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.5/bin/lrelease:   /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by         /home/user/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.5/bin/lrelease)
    /home/user/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.5/bin/lrelease: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by    /home/user/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.5/bin/lrelease) 
    gmake[1]: *** [assistant_cs.qm] Error 1
```

And, I have found the `libstdc++.so.6` in `$HOME/softwares/lib64`, and I have add the path into `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, why the `make` command just use the system's library, not use the provided one? I have no root privileges, so I can't link the system's library with my home gcc's library. Could you give me some advice, please? Thanks.